# while making service worker file this error is occuring

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

index.js:1 Registration failed: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/js/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/js/service-worker.js'): A bad HTTP response code (400) was received when fetching the script.